# Ошибка импорта пакета ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, linux, импорт, package

на винде проект имеет такую структуру
[image: структура на винде]
и при запуске

```
from package.settings import *
print(bool_choice_db)
```

в файле test.py в папке point_game результат выводится правильно, но при запуске на вдс на дебиане получаю ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хотя структура одинаковая

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]